# shiny R slider with few values

Tags: r, plot, shiny, slider, histogram

I need to use a slider while plotting my histogram. The thing is, it is not really good when I use it. The only working values here (from 1 to 36) are 3, 5, 9, 25, 36. So, I would like to change the slider and make available only those values.
This is my code:
CLIENT

```
h2('Percentuale di cacao'),
    # Slider per l'istogramma della percentuale di cacao
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins1", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 36, value = 10),

        ),
        # Plot dell'istogramma 
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot1")
        )
    ),
```

SERVER

```
output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins1)
        hist(chocolate$CocoaPerc, nclass = input$bins1, xlab="Percentuale di cacao", main="Frequenza della percentuale
            di cacao", col = c("chocolate", "chocolate3", "chocolate2", "chocolate4"))
    })
```

I saw other questions where some users answered to use shinyWidgets, but after seeing the documentation, I still have no idea of how i could put it here. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `sliderTextInput` from `shinyWidgets` package.
You provide the different values for choices and as you get the value in input as text you must cast them to numbers before use.

UI

```
...
sliderTextInput("bins1", "Number of bins:", choices=c("3", "5", "9", "25", "36"))
...
```

SERVER

```
...
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = as.integer(input$bins1))
... nclass = as.integer(input$bins1) ...
...
```

Comment: It returns me this error: *Error in sliderInput("bins1", "Number of bins:", choices = c("3", "5",  : 
  unused argument (choices = c("3", "5", "9", "25", "36"))*

Comment: I think that was a typo - the code should be `sliderTextInput` rather than `sliderInput`.

Comment: Arrgh "Copy paste" of your code. Too quick :-). Corrected my answer